# Target file fails during INSTALL stage with CMake

Tags: cmake

I have a `CMakeLists.txt` file that is building a *shared* lib as en `ExternalProject` and this lib needs to be installed in a specific location so that it can be picked up by the main project at build time. I am using the following line to perform the install process:

```
install(FILES $<TARGET_FILE:of_shared> DESTINATION oF/lib)
```

However, this fails:

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:31 (FILE):
file INSTALL cannot find
"/Users/me/packages/builds/x86_64/of-0.9.3-osx-release/$<TARGET_FILE:of_shared>".


make[3]: *** [install] Error 1
make[2]: *** [of_shared-prefix/src/of_shared-stamp/of_shared-install] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/of_shared.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This might be a compatibility bug of some sort, maybe between CMake versions. I am using CMake 2.8.12.

These are the related CMake lines:

```
add_library(core OBJECT ${OF_SOURCE_FILES})
add_library(of_shared SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:core>)

set_target_properties(of_shared PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set_target_properties(of_shared PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME openFrameworks)

target_link_libraries(of_shared ${OF_CORE_FRAMEWORKS} ${OF_ADDON_FRAMEWORKS} ${OF_CORE_LIBS} ${OF_ADDON_LIBS})

install(FILES $<TARGET_FILE:of_shared> DESTINATION oF/lib)
install(FILES libs/fmodex/lib/osx/libfmodex.dylib DESTINATION oF/lib)
install(DIRECTORY libs/glut/lib/osx/GLUT.framework DESTINATION .)
```

Obviously that bit with the `$<TARGET_FILE:of_shared>` is failing. Apart from that, everything is working. I can see the shared lib being created.

Comment: Maybe I should be using something like this:
`install(TARGETS mySharedLib LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)` instead of `install(FILES ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution myself. Instead of using:

```
install(FILES $<TARGET_FILE:of_shared> DESTINATION openFrameworks/lib)
```

One should use:

```
install(TARGETS of_shared LIBRARY DESTINATION openFrameworks/lib)
```

In that case `of_shared` is the name of the library.